# Query grouped by a column other than DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I am adding up the DISTINCT values in two columns, but I need to group the data by a separate column. Here is an example of my MySQL table structure:

```
   customer category    amount1    amount2
     1      food        100        200
     1      drink       100        200
     1      home        200        100
```

and here is my current query:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount1) AS total1, SUM(DISTINCT amount2) AS total2 
FROM groceries GROUP BY customer.
```

The problem is as follows: If the grouping is by customer then total1 for customer 1 = 300, but if the grouping is by category then total1 = 400.

I have an application that starts with a high level customer view, grouped by customer, and then drills down to the category level just as I have described and the two numbers do not match.

My category view matches the data, but my customer total is off; how can I change the query above to match reflect the data correctly and still group by customer?

Comment: Remove the `distinct` and the sum's will be consistent across queries.  In my experience, `sum(distinct)` and `avg(distinct)` should never be necessary.  They are evidence of poor query design or poor table layouts.

Comment: The problem is the client has tons of duplicate data in the table and the only way to normalize is to use DISTINCT. If I dont do that then the SUM will add up all of the duplicate items and then client has specified only using one of each duplicate.

Comment: . . If the client has specified to only use one of each duplicate, then what you are doing is right, and their logic is wrong.  They need someone to help them figure out the right logic, if they want correct answers.

Comment: Thats good to hear..:) Id like to go back to them with a proposal, what could I suggest they add to the table to accomplish what they want as far as the view knowing the duplicates wont be removed, but they could add a column,etc.

Comment: . . I don't know.  It is unclear from your question what the right values should be.  I suspect though that there is some sort of hierarchy or dimensional schema, and these values should be stored in another table.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Gordon. As always you've been very helpful.